# detect a device using batch file

Tags: batch-file

is there a way to detect a new device thats been plugged into the computer using dos.Specifically, its a network adapter. I want to do something like "wait for network adapter" in a dos batch file. I'm running Windows XP.

Comment: There are lots of detail you may want to add.  Do you know anyting about the network adapter in advance (like mac address or IP address)?  Is it a USB adapter?

Answer (score 1):

This may be ok:
Limitations:  It doesnt respond when no driver is available.
USB insertions are cumulative.  you'll need other criteria to see a re-inserted device.

You may have better results running [Nirsofts USB Device Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)
In Options, Advanced Options, you can specify an action, like 'run batch file'.

Nic.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set last=foo
set nic=foo


:setup

@for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%i in ('wmic nic get caption /format:list') do @set last=%%i


:loop

@for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%i in ('wmic nic get caption /format:list') do @set nic=%%i


@echo last is %last%. and nic is %nic%.

if %last%. == . set last=%nic%

if not %last%. == %nic%. goto :somethingchanged

wait -k 30
goto loop

goto exit

:somethingchanged
@echo - Hey!  A nic got inserted...
goto setup

:exit
```